# Using facet_wrap or facet_grid with fixed number of facets in R and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I used Nsaunders' rather [nice to follow approach of using facet_grid in ggplot2 for a gantt-style diagram](https://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2010/04/14/plotting-time-of-day-data-using-ggplot2/).

But I'm facing a problem. It is ment to be a schedule with a fixed number of rooms and the data comes from a SQL-Database. On some days not all rooms are booked. But I nevertheless want them to be plotted.

So here is my code of the plot

```
# The data
tasks <- data.frame(
task  = as.factor(dataset$NUMMER),
date  =  dataset$BEGINN,
start =dataset$BEGINN,
end = dataset$ENDE,
room = as.factor(dataset$RAUM))

# Names of the rooms
y_labels = c('1.01', '1.02', '1.03', '1.04', '1.05', '1.09', '1.11', '1.12', '1.13', '1.22')

# offset tasks in plot if > 1 per room
tasks$ymin <- c(rep(0, nrow(tasks)))
t <- table(tasks$room)
for(room in rownames(t)) {
   if(t[[room]] > 1) {
      ss <- tasks[tasks$room== room,]
      y  <- 0
      for(i in as.numeric(rownames(ss))) {
         tasks[i,]$ymin <- y
         y <- y + 1.2
      }
   }
}

# plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(tasks, aes(xmin = start.hour, xmax = end.hour, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymin + 1)) + 
        geom_rect(fill = tasks$fill) + 
        geom_text(aes(x = start.hour + 0.2, y = ymin +.5, label=task), hjust="left") +
        facet_wrap(~room, nrow=8, drop=FALSE, strip.position= "left", as.table=FALSE, scales="free_y") +
        xlim(7,22) +
        scale_y_discrete(breaks = y_labels, labels= y_labels) +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22), labels=c("7:00", "8:00", "9:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00"))
```

[This leads to the following visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z06Ep.png)
This is quite alright. [But this is what I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cLM5.png)

If anyone had an idea of how I can make all the rooms visible - even if they don't have values for this day, I would be very pleased.
Thank you in advance for your help.

This would be the data of one day. As you can see there are no values for room "1.11" and "1.22". But I would still like to plot those rooms.

```
task = c("20181BTDS198401", "20181BTDT569202","20171BMQ1135404", "20181BTDM274201", "20171BTDG524192", "20171BTDT981303", "20181BTQ1135001", "20171BTDB253801", "20181DNMA894501","20181BTDK906502", "20181BTDK908902", "20181BMR2854901", "20181BTQ1184401")

date = c("2018-02-22", "2018-02-22", "2018-02-22", "2018-02-22", "2018-02-22", "2018-02-22", "2018-02-22", "2018-02-22","2018-02-22", "2018-02-22", "2018-02-22", "2018-02-22", "2018-02-22")

start = c("18:00:00", "08:30:00", "18:00:00", "09:00:00", "14:00:00", "08:30:00", "18:00:00", "17:30:00", "09:00:00", "16:30:00", "18:00:00", "08:30:00", "18:00:00")

end = c("20:30:00", "16:00:00", "20:30:00", "16:30:00", "20:40:00", "13:00:00", "20:30:00", "21:30:00", "15:20:00", "18:00:00", "19:40:00", "13:20:00", "20:30:00")

room = c("1.01", "1.02", "1.02", "1.03", "1.04", "1.05", "1.05", "1.09", "1.12", "1.12", "1.12", "1.13", "1.13")
```

Comment: please give a reproducible example, that is a part of your dataset data frame

Comment: I added the data of one day to the post above

Comment: Don't use `tasks$` in your `aes`, especially when facetting! Things can go horribly wrong that way. (Also your plotting code is not legal code). I think for your answer, use `drop = FALSE` in `facet_wrap` (though `facet_grid` seems easier here).

Comment: Thx @Axeman for your response and the hint with `tasks$` in my `aes`. As I'm new to R, would you be so kind to point out, why the plotting code is not legal. Regarding `drop = FALSE`: I tried it - as you can see in the code. But it does not work.

Comment: You're missing parentheses, copy and pasting your code simply doesn't work. Try setting your factor levels appropriately (including the rooms that aren't showing). I.e. `tasks$room <- factor(tasks$room, y_labels)`.

Comment: @Axeman. Thx again. I will try this. By the way. I fixed the missing parentheses in the plotting-code and got rid of the `tasks$` in the `aes`

Comment: @Axeman. Unfortunately `tasks$room <- factor(tasks$room, y_labels)` didn't do the trick but raised an error. "Error in if (zero_range(range)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"